# Have the Dropdown list of an android spinner displayed larger content than the spinner

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

My app displays a Spinner in its actionbar. The text displayed in the spinner can be truncated when it's too long. The problem is that when I press on the spinner, the dropdown items are using the same width than the spinner. This means that some entries are truncated as well even though there's enough space on the right of the drop down item to display the truncated text...
Is there a way to use a wrap_content kind of width for the drop down items ?
For now I'm using the default android layout:

> android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item